# UIButton setTitleColor forState works well, while setTitle does not

Tags: ios, uibutton

From the questions on SO, I know that it's correct to change button label text with `setTitle ... forState`:

```
[_capturing_button setTitle:@"take photo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

In my code, on user click I want to disable button and set text `"processing"`, and when processing finished, enable button back.

But when disabling button, text disappears.

```
-(void) initCapturingButton
{
   _capturing_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    const int width = 150, height = 30;
   _capturing_button.frame = CGRectMake( _main_view.frame.size.width / 2.0 - width / 2.0, 2, width, height );
   _capturing_button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

   [_capturing_button setTitle:@"take photo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [_capturing_button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   //[_capturing_button setTitle:@"processing" forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; 
   [_capturing_button setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

   _capturing_button.enabled = YES;

   [_capturing_button addTarget:self action:@selector(onCapturingButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [_topToolBar addSubview:_capturing_button];
```

}

On button click, I just disable the button:

```
-(void) onCapturingButtonClick
{
     _capturing_button.enabled = NO;
}
```

And when processing finishes, enable button back:

```
  -(void) processingFinished
  {
       _capturing_button.enabled = YES;
  }
```

With this code, when app is in processing mode, button text has purple color, when in capturing mode, color is white. But if I uncomment the line with setting title for disabled state, text disappers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and examining the state of the button? Can you confirm that the title text is set even if it does not show i the UI?

Comment: @fragilecat: Yes, I tried that. State is `UIControlStateDisabled` and text is "processing".

Comment: What happens if you replace  the line of code with [_capturing_button setTitle:@"take photo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just just disabling the in the onCapturingButtonClick method not changing the button state you can set the title for UIControlStateNormal.

```
-(void) onCapturingButtonClick
{
     [_capturing_button setTitle:@"processing" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
     _capturing_button.enabled = NO;
}
```

And then in your processingFinished method:

```
  -(void) processingFinished
  {
      [_capturing_button setTitle:@"take photo!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       _capturing_button.enabled = YES;
  }
```

From the [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State) Class Reference Document:

> UIControlStateDisabled
>
> Disabled state of a control. This state indicates that the control is currently > disabled. You can retrieve and set this value through the enabled property.